# repeating background image which is from 'image map' using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a image map (sorry for sloppy drawing...)

[image]

The number means x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width, height.
For example, `5, 5, 25, 25` means that this image is located at `(5, 5)` and has `width 25px` and `height 25px`.

(the last image's size is wrong. `100, 5, 5, 25` is correct size.

And I want to make

[image]

using above image map with width 100px and height 25px.

At this time, I use image map as following.

```
#aDiv {
    width: 25px; height 25px;
    background-image:url('path');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-5px -5px;
}
```

with one tag

```
<div></div>
```

for background.

But I have no idea that making something like second image using first image (image map).
How can I do this?

The above code is what I have done. I have no idea totally. The last idea I have is

```
#one { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px; height:25px;
    background-image:url('path');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-5px -5px;
}

#two { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px; height:25px;
    background-image:url('path');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-100px -5px;
}


#three { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:5px; height:25px;
    background-image:url('path');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-50px -5px;
}

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

But in this way, the total width is just 75 pixel. I need to repeat `#two`, i.e., repeating the third drawing of image map.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean, so you need to post the code you have so far, so we can see how it behaves now, and hopefully that will clarify things for us

Comment: sorry... actually I have been used a image map only as above code. Just one tag and `background-position` and `background-repeat`. I guess I need to repeat image of second drawing of image map... But I don't know how...

Comment: You still need to post a _working_ code snippet, with visible image and all ... I mean, what we see is one div and one rule, but it appears to be 4 images, each 25px wide. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @LGSon I upload my code. thanks for your advice

Comment: Posted an answer. Comment on that if I got it right or I need to adjust or delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is difficult to fully understand what you want, here is 2 versions, so we get some visuals from where to work out a proper solution.

*Note, I added a border around each div so one easily see how they split/position the image map*

Sample 1: 3 div's using the same map, positioned so it still looks as 1, where the second is twice the width as the rest.

```css
div {
    float: left;                /* temp, to set them side by side  */
    border: 1px solid black;    /* temp. for demo purpose          */
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 400px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsnl6.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200px; 
    background-position: -100px 0;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background-position: -300px 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

Sample 2: With 4 div's instead.

```css
div {
    float: left;                /* temp, to set them side by side  */
    border: 1px solid black;    /* temp. for demo purpose          */
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 400px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsnl6.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
    background-position: -100px 0;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    background-position: -200px 0;
}
div:nth-child(4) {
    background-position: -300px 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer !!!! I cant test your code but I can understand your code. I will test it tomorrow but I check for right answer. Thank you so much !! :)

Comment: @wallah Drop me a note if it doesn't work out and I help to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing fine with your CSS, I think the only pointer you'll need is that you can just adapt an HTML structure which fit your needs:

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel__top-left"></div>
    <div class="panel__top"></div>
    <div class="panel__top-right"></div>
</div>
```

In this way you can add CSS to target `.panel__top-left`, `.panel__top` and `.panel__top-right`.

Comment: according to image map, in this way, the total width is just 75 pixel. I need to longer width than it (100 pixel). So I need to repeat third drawing from image map.

Answer (score 1):

Since we want to style our background we should use pseudo-elemets.
also it could be done with more than one div easier.

transform: scaleX(-1) will flip pseudo-element. 
be careful with background-positioning.

:before contains first image, aDIV contains third image (----) and :after contains fliped of first image.
also we use z-index:-1 to put middle image on the bahind of two background and lose vertical edge by this hack.

```
#aDIV:before
{
content:" ";
width:75px;
height:25px;
background-image:url('path');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:-5px -5px;
}    

 #aDIV:after
{
content:" ";
width:75px;
height:25px;
background-image:url('path');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:45px -5px;
transform: scaleX(-1);
}

#aDIV
{
 width:75px;
 height:25px;
 z-index:-1;
 background-image:url('path');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:20px -5px;
}
```